# Comparing DateTime fields with different 'times'

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

My program asks for the user to enter a date which is then converted to a datetime:

```
var fromDate = DateTime.Parse(txtFromDate.Text);
```

The reason I'm converting it to a DateTime field is because I want to compare it against DateTime fields in a table, like so:

```
var q = gc.GraphicRequests.Where(a => a.DateInWork == fromDate);
```

However, there's a problem.  When the user inputs a date (6/17/2013) and it's converted to a DateTime field, the result date looks like this:  **6/17/2013 12:00:00 AM**.

The problem is, when I'm trying to find records in the table that match that date, I'm not getting any hits because the dates in the table look like this: **6/17/2013 05:35 AM** or some other time.  So, the date is correct, but the time doesn't match.

My question is, how can I just compare the dates and leave out the time?  I just want every record that matches that date, regardless of what time is on the DateTime field.

Comment: Which query provider are you using?  Linq to sql, EF, etc.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try using the [`Date`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx) property, which represents the current `DateTime` without any `Time` part:

```
var q = gc.GraphicRequests.Where(a => a.DateInWork.Date == fromDate);
```

If `DateInWork` is nullable (i.e. `DateTime?`), use this:

```
var q = gc.GraphicRequests.Where(a => 
    a.DateInWork.HasValue && a.DateInWork.Value.Date == fromDate);
```

However, if you are using Entity Framework, you may need to look at the [`TruncateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd395596.aspx) method:

```
var q = gc.GraphicRequests.Where(a =>
    EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(a.DateInWork).Value == fromDate);
```

Comment: Will the query provider know how to translate that?

Comment: Is there a certain 'using directive' I need to have in order to use this Date property?  When I add the .Date I get a squiggly red underline.EDIT: I found it: System.Date.Time.  Doh!

Comment: @JavaRox What's the type of that property?  If it's a `DateTime`, it will have a `Date` property.

Comment: @Servy depends on the query provider, which OP hasn't specified.

Comment: This is Linq to SQL.  And, for some reason, the editor still doesn't like the .Date propery even after adding the using directive System.DateTime.

Comment: @JavaRox I don't think that's even a valid namespace. If `DateInWork` is nullable you'll have to use `.Value.Date`. See my updated answer.

Comment: @JavaRox If your provider doesn't support that kind of comparison, you could still compare the individual components (Y/M/D).

Comment: Your second scenario worked just fine, p.s.w.g.  For some reason, I can't use .Date on the DateInWork field, so I opted to use your second solution.  I thank you for your help!

Comment: @JavaRox Glad to help. **Further Reading:** [Nullable Types (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

If your query provider is able to translate it, this would be the option that semantically represents what you want to do:

```
var q = gc.GraphicRequests.Where(a => a.DateInWork.HasValue 
    && a.DateInWork.Value.Date  == fromDate);
```

If it doesn't, just see if the date is between the start and end of the day:

```
DateTime someDate;
DateTime fromDate = someDate.Date, toDate = someDate.Date.AddDays(1);

var q = gc.GraphicRequests.Where(a => a.DateInWork >= fromDate 
    && a.DateInWork < toDate);
```

Comment: Well, for whatever reason, I cannot append .Date to the a.DateInWork field (nullable DateTime?).  So, I used your second scenario and, of course, it worked.  I was trying to get away from doing something like this though because I was sure that I could use something like .Date, but I can't seem to make it work.  I can append .Date to the fromDate with no problem.  It just won't let me append to DateInWork.  Ah well.  I do appreciate yours and everyone else's help!

Comment: @JavaRox You didn't state that your date is nullable; that changes the problem.  This is why you should answer the [clarifying questions asked of you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17303010/comparing-datetime-fields-with-different-times/17303152?noredirect=1#comment25091735_17303037).  When you don't it's much harder to help you.

Comment: Sorry about that, Servy!  I'll pay more attention next time to the questions that are asked of me.

Comment: @JavaRox If this answer (or any other) has helped you, even if it wasn't the solution you ended up going with, you should probably upvote it. It helps others know that this was a valuable solution that may aid them in the future; plus it encourages users to supply good, well thought-out answers, like *Servy*'s.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using entity framework, then use [EntityFunctions.TruncateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd395596.aspx) method:

```
var q = gc.GraphicRequests
          .Where(a => EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(a.DateInWork) == fromDate);
```

If you are using Linq to SQL, then you can simply asses `DateTime.Date` property. Or even do things like `a.DateInWork.Date.Year > 2000`.

Comment: He's not using EF, [he's using linq to sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17303010/comparing-datetime-fields-with-different-times/17303152#comment25091817_17303037).

Comment: @Servy then he simply can access `Date` property. BTW provider was not specified before

Comment: I know, that's why I commented, allowing you to edit your answer based on the new information.